# How to read a value from properties file in a javascript file

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, spring-boot, properties-file

I have a spring-boot project which serves angularjs. Both the front-end and back-end code are in the same project.

In my angularjs service.js files I am calling the back-end service.
I have different urls in the different properties file. I want to read them as per profile selection. I know how to read properties file in a Java class but I am not sure how to read values from properties file in a javascript file.

As shown below:

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that JS files are executed in the browser and dont have the same type of access to props file as JVM.

Comment: Try creating a json file instead of properties file and then make an ajax call to read it.

Comment: The JS run in the browser on the client, and the property files are on the server, so the JS files *cannot* read the property files (directly). You either need to make the JS files dynamically generated so the server can inject the property values, or you need to make an AJAX call to the server to retrieve the properties.

Answer (score 0):

Some options:

1. create a separate config.json for your angular APP (manage it manually).
2. use maven resource plugin to filter placeholders for your config.json file (automated). E.g. read in one place and substitute in another (but I don't like this way).
3. Or create an API to return data from from your properties file as JSON. 
   https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html